# PostgreSQL stored procedures

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, winforms

I'm new to PostgreSQL. I have a Winforms app that's calling to a PostgreSQL database. Instead of passing in the query, I'd rather use PostgreSQL paramaterised stored procedures. I am able to call and get a return for a parameterless stored procedure, but when I add parameters and execute the call, I get an error saying that column `userId` doesn't exist.

`userid` is the parameter.

On PostgreSQL, when creating the sp, I also create an `IN` argument with that is the same type and name.

What am I missing here?

The SQL is a simple:

```
select * 
from public.users u 
where u.userid = userid
```

Comment: try renaming parameter in Postgresql Stored Procedure with _userId it is conflicting with table column

Answer (score 0):

use it to identify a parameter in SQL:

```
Select * from public.users u where u.userid = @userid
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, bvut when i try that, i get this error on postgres:
ERROR: operator does not exist: @ character varying
LINE 4: ...ODY$Select * from public.users u where u.userid = @userid$BO...
^
HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type. You might need to add an explicit type cast

Comment: i use postgres to create the stored proc and use their wizard tool in doing so.

the only options i set are the 

Under the 'General' tab - Name
Under the language tab - Language = SQL
Under the language tab - Code = Select * from public.users u where u.userid = @userid

Under the Arguments tab - Data type = character varying
Under the Arguments tab - Mode = IN
Under the Arguments tab - Argument Name = userid


when i call this sp, i get the error, when i add the '@' i get the error i just mentioned in the above reply

Answer (score 0):

You indicated that you "create an IN argument with that thats same (t)ype and name". That is not quite what you do want to do. While you do want the type to be the same the name must either different or qualified by the function name. If it the same you will get all rows as the intended parameter name will be interpreted as the column name; basically resulting in:

```
Select * from table_name where column_name = column_name;
```

Which is true whenever the value isn't null. Now there are 2 approaches, using userid and assuming its unique:

```
create or replace function get_user(userid_in users.userid%type)
returns setof users
language sql
as $$
    select *
      from users where userid = userid_in ; 
$$;
```

OR

```
create or replace function get_user(userid users.userid%type)
returns setof users
language sql
as $$
    select *
      from users where userid = get_user.userid ; 
$$;
```